# Change cd default directory (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, cd

I'm looking for a way to change the default directory of cd, and I'm wondering if this is possible. I tried adding

```
alias "cd=cd ~/Documents/Github"
```

to .bashrc, but this obviously doesn't work because it breaks the cd command so that you cannot use cd for anything but going to that directory. Is there some export that I could put in .bashrc to do this? I do not want to change my home directory, just the default directory cd goes to. I ask because I regularly use cd to change to my default directory that I am programming in and would like to not have to type `cd ~/workspace` or `cd` and then `cd workspace` every time I want to change to the directory `~/workspace`.

Comment: Use a new alias: `alias cdd="cd /your/new/dir"`

Comment: I thought of this as well, but I would rather not have to use a different command to cd to that directory. Thanks though

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a simpler alternative using an **alias**:

```
alias cd='HOME=~/Documents/Github cd'
```

- While this redefines `$HOME`, it does so ONLY for the `cd` command, so should be safe(*).
- This also obviates the need for any custom parameter pre-parsing.

If you place this in `~/.bashrc`, you should get the desired behavior.

Note that, by default, this alias will NOT be in effect in *scripts* (non-interactive shells), as alias expansion is by default *disabled* there (use `shopt -s expand_aliases` to explicitly enable).

---

(*) @chepner points out one restriction: with the alias in place you won't be able to do `HOME=/somewhere/else cd`, i.e., you won't be able to redefine (override) `$HOME` *again*, *ad-hoc*. As he further states, though, it's hard to imagine why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: +1 Other than not being able to use the alias with `HOME=/somewhere/else cd` (and seriously, why would you?), this is much simpler than my shell function.

Comment: +1 A couple of the other answers worked as well, but I liked this one the best. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. @chepner: Thanks for that: for the sake of completeness I've added it to the answer.

Comment: As to why someone might want to... I have projects and I usually work on a particular project.  I thought it might be nice if I had a simply way to cd back to the top directory of the project.  So, when I start working on a project I could do PROJECT=`pwd` and then edit the cd function below to default to $PROJECT if it is set.

Answer (score 5):

You can shadow the builtin `cd` command with a shell function. Add the following to your `.bashrc` file.

```
cd () {
    if [ $# = 0 ]; then
        builtin cd ~/Documents/Github
    else
        builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

This isn't perfect, as it assumes you will never call the function as

```
* cd -L
* cd -P
* cd -LP
* etc
```

(that is, using one or more of the supported options without an explicit directory.)

---

UPDATE

This might be a little more comprehensive, but I haven't tested it.

```
cd () {
    local -a args
    while getopts LP opt "$@"; do
        case $opt in
          -*) args+=( "$opt" ) ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    # Assume at most one directory argument, since
    # that is all cd uses
    args+=( "${1:-~/Documents/Github}" )

    builtin cd "${args[@]}"
}
```

Comment: Yes, `~/.bashrc` would be the appropriate place for this; that file is sourced by each *interactive* shell immediately after starting. (Note that any scripts you write will continue to use the real `cd`, not this function.)

Answer (score 1):

this is default home location

```
$ pwd
/home/######
```

now you can reset it like this

```
$ export HOME=/tmp
$ cd
$ pwd
/tmp
```

now it's up to you where to put the new $HOME definition - `.bashrc`, or whatever

Comment: Isn't that a little dangerous - what if other scripts use `$HOME`?

Comment: @Andrew That was my concern as well. I don't really want to change the home directory, just the functionality of cd.

Comment: Changing `HOME` is a bad idea. Most programs will look in `$HOME` for their configuration files; for example, `vim` looks for `$HOME/.vimrc` on startup.

Comment: I did it a couple of times when the homes were mounted in some unusual location, so I guess it's fine in some cases.